# Запуск сайта на не статическом ip

Tags: ip

Приветствую ХешКод).Я собирался запустить свой мини проект,взял у провайдера статический ip,все подготовил и настроил,потом решил проверить статический ip или нет,оказалось нет.Очень стало грустно,у нас тут другого провайдера нет(самый хороший интернет именного у этого провайдера),а проект запустить хочется.Я понимаю,что нужен именно статический ip и никакой другой,но нет его у меня.Вопрос может быть не для ХешКода,но тут сидит много специалистов хороших,так,что заранее извиняюсь.

Что вообще посоветуете сделать,может у какого провайдера мтс ,билайн,есть нормальные статические ip.(мне известен диапазон моего ip,это типо такой статический,так только,конечно,провайдер думает))

Answer (score 2):

Не рекомендуется запускать web проекты на домашнем ПК. Лучше взять хостинг или vps.
Внешние статические ip в последнее время всё реже выдают. Проверьте всех провайдеров к которым подключен дом, зачастую внешний ip выдают местные небольшие компании.

То что вы ищите может называться так:

Внешний выделенный статический реальный белый постоянный ip адрес.

Часто менеджеры не понимают разницы между ними и могут сказать, что они предоставляют такую услугу, но на самом деле ip будет либо статическим, но внутренним либо внешним,но динамическим.

Если прям ну очень нужно, и нет другой возможности то:

```
1. Радио интернет. 
цена: 8000-15000 тыс. подключение.
технология: wimax
скорость: 2 мбит/c.
особенности: нужен доступ на крышу или подходящий балкон для установки вышки.

2. skylink. 
цена: 2000-5000 тыс. модем. 
технология: EV-DO
скорость: 0.1 - 5 мбит/c (может уже есть 120 мбит/c), отдача 150 кб/с.
особенности: очень медленная отдача и жуткие тормоза для сервера. Внешний ip поддерживают только тарифы с лимитом на скачивание и отдачу.

3. (возможно)Спутниковый интернет с двусторонним доступом. Здесь точно не уверен.
4. Завести выделенную линию в дом. Если есть достаточно денег.
```

Comment: Спасибо,а если ,допустим, внешний ip?
(у мтс билайна нету?).Да вы,что я все хочу на домашнем пк,это как-то поднимает дух))прям с железом покапаться)

Comment: Вроде есть DynDns,или что-то подобное только там все плавтно,а есть бесплатное что-нить?

Comment: Нет, у этих операторов нет внешнего статического ip. Если вам только сайт поднять и не парится, то берите хостинг. А если именно обучаетесь, то конечно желателен внешний ip. Так как помимо собственных dns он может использоваться и в других случаях.

Опять же, все эти окольные пути вроде DynDns не очень рекомендуются.
Тестируйте сайт на домашнем сервере с локальным ip 192.168.1.1, а потом уже выкладывайте для общего доступа просто изменив ip в конфигах самого сайта.

В вашем случаи самый дешевый вариант, это найти местного провайдера с такой услугой и завести в дом вторую линию для сервера.

Answer (score 2):

Есть сервисы для организации динамического DNS. Вспомнил только [NoIP](http://www.noip.com/personal/) (см. бесплатный NoIP Free внизу страницы). Поищите аналогичные русские.

Answer (score 1):

Провайдер не думает, если у вас в тех. данных контракта написано что `статический`, значит так и есть. Другой вопрос в том внутренний он или внешний:

[Внутренний ip](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81)

Comment: Нет,просто,когда ip статический,то при выключение модема и заходе,например,на яндекс интрометр,он должен оставаться тем же,а тут разный